# Pass in CLI option with npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to pass along a command line option to `node` using `npm start`, namely `--debug`.

I can pass along an argument that is appended to the corresponding start command. For instance, `npm start -- --debug` would execute `node server.js "--debug"` (assuming `"start":"node server.js"`). However, this does not work. `--debug` is an option and must come before the script (`server.js`). More specifically, I'm trying to run `node "--debug" server.js`.

Is there any clean way to do this?

Thank you.

Edit: A constraint is that I can't edit the *package.json* file. Can only edit the `npm` command.

Comment: So the _only_ thing you can control is what you pass to `npm start`? You can't even, say, run `node --debug app.js` directly?

Comment: That is correct. I can only pass things through `npm start`.

Comment: Is this a linux environment?

Comment: Yes, it is a linux environment. I could parse the package.json file and insert the option as the second argument, but that's a bit hacky.

Comment: Even being "clever" with something like `function node() { /usr/local/bin/node --debug "$@"; }; npm start` doesn't work either: `npm` will just run that as `npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]`. (That will work as an alias for `node app.js` though...)

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a `debug` script to `package.json`?

```
{ "scripts" :
  {
    "start" : "node app.js",
    "debug" : "node --debug app.js"
  }
}
```

Use it with `npm run debug`.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I should have been clearer. I can't edit the package.json file. Amended my original post.

Comment: @Citronen Ok. I'll leave the answer here for others who find it via Google, since it might respond to the existing question title for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a module but this is what commander is for: `npm install --save commander`

```
var program = require('commander');

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .option('-d, --debug', 'Debug Mode')
  .parse(process.argv);

if (program.debug) {
  // do debug stuff
}else{
  // proceed normally
}
```

if you don't want to use commander, node exposes arguments like this (process.argv):

`['node', 'yourScript.js', '--debug']`

so you could just check `if(process.argv.length >= 3 && process.argv[2] == '--debug') doStuff();`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to pass it through the `npm start` command. The following hack can work, but note the race condition.

```
((sleep 2 && kill -s USR1 $(pgrep node)) &) && npm start -d
```